# How do I check if a record has the oldest timestamp or not in a one-to-many join in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, one-to-many

I have two tables, named **incident** and **action**.
Each incident has many actions. 
Each action has a timestamp for when it was completed.

I want to select all the actions, like this:

```
select action.completed, * from action
left join incident on incident.id = action.incidentid
```

and then I want to generate a boolean value that tells me if each action is the first one completed or not, per incident.

Example: for incident 2, action 6 was completed first. For incident 3, action 10 was completed first. This is the output I want:

```
completed            | completed_first | actionid | incidentid | ...
---------------------+-----------------+----------+------------+-----
2017-01-01 02:23:30  | false           |     5    |    2       |
2017-01-01 01:00:00  | true            |     6    |    2       |
2017-01-01 05:23:30  | false           |     7    |    2       |
2017-01-01 00:30:00  | false           |     8    |    3       |
NULL                 | false           |     9    |    3       |
2017-01-01 00:10:00  | true            |    10    |    3       |
```

So how do I generate the **completed_first** column?

Note that completed=NULL should not qualify as completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row_number in a CTE and a case:

```
with ACTION_T as
(
select a1.*, 
       row_number() over(partition by incidentid 
                         order by coalesce(completed,
                                           getdate())) as a_ord  -- Using a getdate() to handle nulls
from action a1
)
select completed,
       case when a_ord = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end as completed_first,
       actionid,
       incidentid
from ACTION_T
```

Comment: `NULL` sorts first, you need to exclude it

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood problem correctly.

Please check below query

```
  SELECT completed ,
  CASE
    WHEN rn = 1
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END AS completed_first ,
  actionid ,
  incidentid
FROM
  (SELECT action.completed,
    actionid ,
    incidentid ,
    row_number() over (partition BY incidentid order by coalesce(action.completed,DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()))) rn
  FROM action
  LEFT JOIN incident
  ON incident.id = action.incidentid
  ) a
```

Comment: `NULL` sorts first, you need to exclude it

Answer (score -1):

```
    Create table [action] (Actionid int, incidentid int,  [Completed] datetime)

    Create table Incident (Incidentid int)

    insert into [incident] values (2), (3)

    insert into [action] values (5 ,2 ,'2017-01-01 02:23:30')
                                , (6, 2,'2017-01-01 01:00:00')
                                , (7, 2,'2017-01-01 05:23:30')
                                , (8, 3,'2017-01-01 00:30:00')
                                , (9, 3, null)
                                , (10, 3, '2017-01-01 00:10:00')
```

> If each Incidents does not have multiple identical times:

```
select action.completed, iif(First.incidentid is null, 'False', 'True') as [Completed_First], action.Actionid, action.incidentID, incident.*
from action
left join incident on incident.Incidentid = action.incidentid
left join (
Select IncidentID, min(completed) as F_Completed
from ACTION
Group BY IncidentID ) First on action.incidentid=first.incidentID and action.completed=first.F_Completed
```

> Accommodates Incidents with multiple identical times:

```
select action.completed, iif(First.M_Actionid is null, 'False', 'True') as [Completed_First], action.Actionid, action.incidentID, incident.*
from action
left join incident on incident.Incidentid = action.incidentid
left join (
Select min(ActionID) as M_ActionID
from action
inner join (
select  incidentid, min(completed) as M_Completed
from action
group by incidentid) ICMin on action.incidentID =  icmin.incidentID and action.completed= icmin.m_completed
group by action.incidentid ) First on action.actionid=first.M_ActionID
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost what i tried at first, but I didn't get it to work.